# Form auto submitting when trying to refer back to change form data

Tags: php, html, forms

So I got an annoying problem with my code here: I have 2 pages `orderstep1.php` and `orderstep2.php`. Orderstep1 has a form where you have to fill in all user details to make a new order. Orderstep2 has a return button to go back to the first page if you've made a mistake. However when you click the button the user stays on the same page. I guess this has to do with the $_POST['submit'] variable already being set and therefore auto submitting the form when you try to get back to the first page.

Here is the code of both pages:
Orderstep1.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php
            session_start();
        ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheets/main_setup.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheets/orderstepbanner.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheets/orderstep1.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/ForumAltering.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(window).width();
            var width = $(window).width();
            var width_Main_Body = width * 0.7;
            var width_Full_Page = width_Main_Body * 0.98;
            var width_Scale_down = width_Full_Page * 0.75;
            var height = width_Scale_down * 0.75;

            $(function() {
                $.post('process.php',{frameH:height},function(json){
                    if(json.outcome == 'success'){

                    }else{
                        alert('Javascript kan uw schermgrootte niet achterhalen. Activeer javascript in uw webbrowser!');
                    }
                },'json');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Main_Body">
            <h1>WaspBane</h1>
            <h5>Wespenvallen van WaspBane&reg;</h5>
            <img src="Images/WaspBane_Banner.png"></img>
            <div id="NAVIGATOR">
                <table id="NavOptions">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="NavOption1"><a href="index.php">Home</a></td>
                        <td id="NavOption2"><a href="orderstep1.php">Bestellen</a></td>
                        <td id="NavOption3"><a href="wasps.php">Wespen</a></td>
                        <td id="NavOption4"><a href="instructions.php">Instructies</a></td>
                        <td id="NavOption5"><a href="manual.php">Handleiding</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="FullPage">
                <div id="OrderStepsBanner">
                    <div id="OrderSteps">
                        <div id="OrderStep1">
                            <ul id="OrderStepFirst">
                                <li id="OrderStepFirstTIN-A"></li><!--
                                --><li id="OrderStepFirstFull-A">
                                    <p class="OrderStepText">Stap 1</p>
                                </li><!--
                                --><li id="OrderStepFirstTOUT-A"></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="OrderStep2">
                            <ul id="OrderStepSecond">
                                <li id="OrderStepSecondTIN"></li><!--
                                --><li id="OrderStepSecondFull">
                                    <p class="OrderStepText">Stap 2</p>
                                </li><!--
                                --><li id="OrderStepSecondTOUT"></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="OrderStep3">
                            <ul id="OrderStepThird">
                                <li id="OrderStepThirdTIN"></li><!--
                                --><li id="OrderStepThirdFull">
                                    <p class="OrderStepText">Stap 3</p>
                                </li><!--
                                --><li id="OrderStepThirdTOUT"></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="OrderStep4">
                            <ul id="OrderStepFourth">
                                <li id="OrderStepFourthTIN"></li><!--
                                --><li id="OrderStepFourthFull">
                                    <p class="OrderStepText">Stap 4</p>
                                </li><!--
                                --><li id="OrderStepFourthTOUT"></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="Orderstep1Form">
                    <form method="post" action="form1submit.php "id="Contact">
                        <table id="FormData">
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Naam:</p></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" <?php if(isset($_SESSION["Name"])){echo "value='".$_SESSION["Name"]."'";};?> required/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Adres:</p></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="Address" id="Address" <?php if(isset($_SESSION["Address"])){echo "value='".$_SESSION["Address"]."'";};?> required/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Woonplaats:</p></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="City" id="City" <?php if(isset($_SESSION["City"])){echo "value='".$_SESSION["City"]."'";};?> required/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Postcode:</p></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="Postal" id="Postal" <?php if(isset($_SESSION["Postal"])){echo "value='".$_SESSION["Postal"]."'";};?> required/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Land:</p></td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="State" id="State" required>
                                        <option value="NL" <?php if(isset($_SESSION["State"])){if($_SESSION["State"] == "NL"){echo "selected";};};?>>Nederland</option>
                                        <option value="BE" <?php if(isset($_SESSION["State"])){if($_SESSION["State"] == "BE"){echo "selected";};};?>>België</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>E-mail:</p></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" <?php if(isset($_SESSION["Email"])){echo "value='".$_SESSION["Email"]."'";};?> required/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Telefoon:</p></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone"<?php if(isset($_SESSION["Phone"])){echo "value='".$_SESSION["Phone"]."'";};?> required/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr colspan="2" class="ContactLinks">
                                <td><input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Volgende"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr colspan="2" class="ContactLinks">
                                <td>
                                    <a class="ContactText" href="mailto:Waspbane@plaagdierbeheer.nl">
                                        <button>Informatie particulieren</button>
                                    </a>
                                    <br><br>
                                    <a class="ContactText" href="mailto:Waspbane@plaagdierbeheer.nl">
                                        <button>Informatie bedrijven en groothandel</button>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div id="Footer">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p id="FooterTrade">&nbsp;Bron: <a id="FooterLink" href="http://www.waspbane.com">WaspBane.com</a></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p id="FooterCopy">&copy; WaspBane.info&nbsp;</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <?php
            date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
            $date = date_create();
            $Date = date_format($date,"Y");
            $Random = round(mt_rand(1000,9999));
            $Code = (string)$Date.(string)$Random;

            if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
                if(isset($_POST["Name"]) and isset($_POST["Address"]) and isset($_POST["City"]) and isset($_POST["Postal"]) and isset($_POST["State"]) and isset($_POST["Email"]) and isset($_POST["Phone"])){
                    $_SESSION["Name"] = $_POST["Name"];
                    $_SESSION["Address"] = $_POST["Address"];
                    $_SESSION["City"] = $_POST["City"];
                    $_SESSION["Postal"] = $_POST["Postal"];
                    $_SESSION["State"] = $_POST["State"];
                    $_SESSION["Email"] = $_POST["Email"];
                    $_SESSION["Phone"] = $_POST["Phone"];
                    $_SESSION["Code"] = $Code;

                    $Country = $_POST["State"];
                    $Language = strtolower($Country);
                    $Street = $_POST["Address"];
                    $Zip = $_POST["Postal"];
                    $City = $_POST["City"];

                    $UFURL = "http://locateandselect.kiala.com/search?order=12345&dspid=DEMO_DSP&country=".$Country."&language=".$Language."&street=".$Street."&zip=".$Zip."&city=".$City."&bckUrl=http://www.testformywebsites.site50.net/orderstep4.php?order=12345%26&target=_parent&gui=sleek&css=http://www.testformywebsites.site50.net/Stylesheets/kiala.css";
                    $FURL = str_replace(" ","+",$UFURL);
                    $_SESSION["URL"] = $FURL;

                    header("Location: orderstep2.php");
                    exit;
                }
            }
        ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Orderstep2.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php
            session_start();
        ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheets/main_setup.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheets/orderstepbanner.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheets/orderstep2.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/ForumAltering.js"></script>
        <script>
            <?php if(isset($_SESSION["Weight"]) or isset($_SESSION["Price"]) or isset($_SESSION["Shipping"])){echo "/*";};?>document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(event){
                var Weigth = document.getElementById("Weight");
                var Price = document.getElementById("Price");
                var Shipping = document.getElementById("Shipping");

                Weight.value = "0.000";
                Price.value = "0.00";
                Shipping.value = "0.00";
            });<?php if(isset($_SESSION["Weight"]) or isset($_SESSION["Price"]) or isset($_SESSION["Shipping"])){echo "*/";};?>

            <?php if(isset($_SESSION["Weight"]) and isset($_SESSION["Price"]) and isset($_SESSION["Shipping"])){
                echo "document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(event){
                    var Weigth = document.getElementById('Weight');
                    var Price = document.getElementById('Price');
                    var Shipping = document.getElementById('Shipping');

                    Weight.value = '".$_SESSION["Weight"]."';
                    Price.value = '".$_SESSION["Price"]."';
                    Shipping.value = '".$_SESSION["Shipping"]."';
                });";
            };
            ?>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Main_Body">
            <h1>WaspBane</h1>
            <h5>Wespenvallen van WaspBane&reg;</h5>
            <img src="Images/WaspBane_Banner.png"></img>
            <div id="NAVIGATOR">
                <table id="NavOptions">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="NavOption1"><a href="index.php">Home</a></td>
                        <td id="NavOption2"><a href="orderstep1.php">Bestellen</a></td>
                        <td id="NavOption3"><a href="wasps.php">Wespen</a></td>
                        <td id="NavOption4"><a href="instructions.php">Instructies</a></td>
                        <td id="NavOption5"><a href="manual.php">Handleiding</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="FullPage">
                <div id="OrderStepsBanner">
                    <div id="OrderSteps">
                        <div id="OrderStep1">
                            <ul id="OrderStepFirst">
                                <li id="OrderStepFirstTIN-F"></li><!--
                                --><li id="OrderStepFirstFull-F">
                                    <p class="OrderStepText">Stap 1</p>
                                </li><!--
                                --><li id="OrderStepFirstTOUT-F"></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="OrderStep2">
                            <ul id="OrderStepSecond">
                                <li id="OrderStepSecondTIN-A"></li><!--
                                --><li id="OrderStepSecondFull-A">
                                    <p class="OrderStepText">Stap 2</p>
                                </li><!--
                                --><li id="OrderStepSecondTOUT-A"></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="OrderStep3">
                            <ul id="OrderStepThird">
                                <li id="OrderStepThirdTIN"></li><!--
                                --><li id="OrderStepThirdFull">
                                    <p class="OrderStepText">Stap 3</p>
                                </li><!--
                                --><li id="OrderStepThirdTOUT"></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="OrderStep4">
                            <ul id="OrderStepFourth">
                                <li id="OrderStepFourthTIN"></li><!--
                                --><li id="OrderStepFourthFull">
                                    <p class="OrderStepText">Stap 4</p>
                                </li><!--
                                --><li id="OrderStepFourthTOUT"></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script>
                    var Country = "<?php echo $_SESSION["State"];?>";
                </script>
                <div id="OrderStep2Form">
                    <form method="post" id="Order">
                        <table id="FormData">
                            <tr colspan="2">
                                <td><p>Selecteer welk product u wil:</p></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Complete wespenval:</p></td>
                                <td><input type="number" name="TrapNumber" id="TrapNumber" min="0" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION["TrapNumber"])){echo $_SESSION["TrapNumber"];}else{echo "0";};?>"  onchange="Calculations(this.value,RefillNumber.value,Country)" required/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Navulling:</p></td>
                                <td><input type="number" name="RefillNumber" id="RefillNumber" min="0" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION["TrapNumber"])){echo $_SESSION["TrapNumber"];}else{echo "0";};?>" onchange="Calculations(TrapNumber.value,this.value,Country)" required/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Totale gewicht:</p></td>
                                <td><output form="Order" name="Weight" id="Weight" for="TrapNumber RefillNumber" value="0"></output></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Totale prijs:</p></td>
                                <td><output form="Order" name="Price" id="Price" for="TrapNumber RefillNumber" value="0"></output></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>Verzendkosten:</p></td>
                                <td><output form="Order" name="Shipping" id="Shipping" for="TrapNumber RefillNumber" value="0"></output></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Volgende"/></td>
                                <td><a href="orderstep1.php"><button>Vorige</button></a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Footer">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p id="FooterTrade">&nbsp;Bron: <a id="FooterLink" href="http://www.waspbane.com">WaspBane.com</a></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p id="FooterCopy">&copy; WaspBane.info&nbsp;</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
                if(isset($_POST["TrapNumber"])){
                    $TrapNumber = $_POST["TrapNumber"];
                    $_SESSION["TrapNumber"] = $_POST["TrapNumber"];
                } else {
                    $TrapNumber = 0;
                    $_SESSION["TrapNumber"] = 0;
                }

                if(isset($_POST["RefillNumber"])){
                    $RefillNumber = $_POST["RefillNumber"];
                    $_SESSION["RefillNumber"] = $_POST["RefillNumber"];
                } else {
                    $RefillNumber = 0;
                    $_SESSION["RefillNumber"] = 0;
                }

                $TotalWeight = (($TrapNumber * 0.75) + ($RefillNumber * 0.125));
                $TotalPrice = (($TrapNumber * 37.95) + ($RefillNumber * 26.95));
                $_SESSION["Weight"] = $TotalWeight;
                $_SESSION["Price"] = $TotalPrice;

                if($TotalWeight >= 15){
                    if($_SESSION["State"] == "NL"){
                        $_SESSION["Shipping"] = 03.95;
                    } elseif($_SESSION["State"] == "BE"){
                        $_SESSION["Shipping"] = 07.50;
                    } else {
                        $_SESSION["Shipping"] = 00.00;
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["Shipping"] = 00.00;
                }

                $header = "Location: orderstep3.php?frameH=".$_SESSION["frameH"];

                header($header);
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see on orderstep2.php the last row of the table:

```
<td><a href="orderstep1.php"><button>Vorige</button></a></td>
```

If anyone has an idea to work this around please tell me. Because I already tried a lot of things but nothing worked so far.

EDIT:

Sorry I missed 1 thing the form action in orderstep1.php shouldn't be there. Forgot to take that one out when changing some things.

Comment: Forgot to say that this is an online test website from myself: http://www.testformywebsites.site50.net. Feel free to see it for yourself. Just go to the tab "Bestellen" fill in the details to go to next page and then click on the button "Vorige"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply post the data to orderstep2.php:

```
<form method="post" action="orderstep2.php "id="Contact">
```

There, you can use your `if($_POST['submit'])`.

On the second page, you should go back with `javascript:history.back()`, so that the form data is still there.

Comment: I already used my own session data to fill in the missing form data when going back but ill try it

Comment: @user3307080: Yes, this is even a better solution.

Comment: Somehow when I add the action to orderstep2 I immediately end up in orderstep3 which is the page after orderstep2.

Comment: Oh god thanks its working with history.back now I had to change up the rest of the ordersteps too to make all continuing problems go away. Ill change up all the back buttons to use history.back

Comment: @user3307080: No problem, thank you for voting. :-) You can also vote up my post, too if you want.

Comment: I only have 1 question about history.back. If the user was to open a different page during the order process and then clicks on the return button will it link back to the external page?

Comment: No, only if he does this in the same tab. And then, he have to open directly the second file.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help. I work a lot with JS but I never heard of history.back :(